# Changing language in windows phone 8.1 universal application

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, globalization, win-universal-app

```
        if (LanguageComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
            (Window.Current.Content as Frame).FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
            HeadingTextBlock.Text = loader.GetString("Setting");
        }
        else if (LanguageComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
            (Window.Current.Content as Frame).FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
            var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
            HeadingTextBlock.Text = loader.GetString("Setting");
        }
```

This is the code I've used in a settings page inside my application. After setting page I'm also setting the flow = right to left and changing heading manually in code.

Problem: Problem is that after setting the language and going back every page has changed language but my home screen still shows english language unless I completely terminate the application and open it again then it shows me arabic on home screen.

Ask If you didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

The resource loader caches the resources so you have to manually drop that cache when you make a change to language. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345029/change-app-language-at-runtime-on-the-fly/20362787#20362787) for more information.