# Windows Phone 8.1 Localization issue

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, localization

I have a huge problem with localization in Windows Phone 8.1.

Namely, I have read all similar questions on StackOverflow, but none is applicable for Windows Phone 8.1 (all of them seem to work on 8.0 and below). The problem I have is that even though I call all of the methods mentioned in [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345029/change-app-language-at-runtime-on-the-fly), but it does not work on Windows Phone 8.1.

The problem seems to be that either resource file does not get set to another language or the UI does not update.

Is there any newer solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried to implement a language selection from the app's settings page?

Comment: Yes, and I reload the page as describe in the mentioned article.

Comment: Is it working correct when you change system language?

Comment: It is working when I restart the app, but it does not refresh the page with new language when I do 
`if (Frame != null)
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage)); `