# UWP - loading resw Resource files dynamically

Tags: c#, uwp, localization, resources

I have a UWP application with Resources.resw for different cultures. They are placed under separate folders e.g: en\Resources.resw, fr\Resources.resw and so on.
I am trying to create a functionality where the user can choose the language dynamically on screen and the strings on the screen be retrieved from the resource file for the selected language.
I have tried :

ResourceContext.SetGlobalQualifierValue("language", Culture.Name);

This works to set the language at the application startup. But doesn't update the language based on user selection. How do I update the language dynamically in an UWP application?

Comment: You could try to set `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` like the official [ApplicationResources-Scenario 8](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/ApplicationResources/cs/scenario8.xaml.cs#L59).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set PrimaryLanguageOverride and then reset the resource manager.

```
  ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = Culture.Name ;
  ResourceManager.Current.DefaultContext.Reset();
```

Then you have to reload the reload the page **Frame.Navigate** and the type of your page.

I originally based my code on [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345029/change-app-language-at-runtime-on-the-fly) which applies to Windows Store applications, but I think it applies to UWP applications as well.